# How can i fix this act (error syntax maybe)

Tags: python

JUST run the simple programm for "changes money" . Error line 7.
For exactly

I tried str and int.

```
d= str(input('customer give')) 
e= d-c
```

and

```
d= int(input('customer give'))
e= d-c
```

also

```
d= input('customer give') 
e= d-c
```

and double quotes

```
a= str(input ('give money')) 
b= int(input ('quantity')) 
c=a*b 
print('the sum is ', c)
d= str(input('customer give')) 
e= d-c 
print ("The change is ", e , 'and customer give ', d)
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/PycharmProjects/learn/learn.py", line 7, in 
>       e= d-c TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

Comment: sorry i need edit this thread and i cant find how

Comment: `input` already returns  a `str` (assuming Python 3); you want to make `a` et al. `int`s (or `float`s) so you can subtract them.

Answer (score 1):

> e= d-c TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

To perform above operation the operands should be of integer or float type

Try this:

```
a= int(input ('give money '))
b= int(input ('quantity '))
c=a*b
print ('the sum is ', c)

d= int(input('customer give '))
e= d-c
print ("The change is ", e , 'and customer give ', d)
```

**Output:**

```
give money 10
quantity 3
the sum is  30
customer give 5
The change is  -25 and customer give  5
```

Comment: Happy to help :)